# Best deploy solution for "Restlet" based server side of an Android Project

Tags: android, mysql, tomcat

I would like to ask you for an opinion about best free/paid server solution for the server side of android app. The server is written using "Restlet". I need application server with MySQL backend support (like "TomCat" & "MySql" on my local machine). I would like to upload the app on GooglePlay for free so i cant afford something expensive. The applicaiton is language learner and the transactions are mostly pushing and pooling words so i guess i dont need huge bandwidht and so on.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine now supports MySQL, and you can write your backend in either Java, Go, or Python.

I have deployed Android apps that use App Engine for the backend.  Even with 30,000 active users, I pay $2.10 per week.

You might be able to squeeze into the free tier, and not pay anything at all.